# Removing "Enter Parameter" without the Analyser Set in Access 2010

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I modified a frm and its associated tbl incorrectly and am now getting the Enter Parameter pop-up for the 6 or 7 fields I altered the names of when I launch the form.  There is only very simple VBA attached to the form doing formatting on OnLoad, GotFocus and LostFocus.

My company hasn't loaded the Analyser toolkit into Access 2010 to let me use Documenter and Analyse tools and I don't have Admin rights.

I have been through the queries, table and form to ensure there are no artefacts lingering but to no avail.

Is there a work-around that anyone's discovered?

Thanks

Comment: Could be the _OrderBy_ and _Filter_ properties of the form, not to say any control bound the a gone field name.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Gustav.  Both the OrderBy and Filter are blank but I believe the problem stems from field names that have now been changed or removed.  I have decided to bite the bullet and reconstruct the form and rewrite the VBA.